# How to set a label to a memory address in ollydbg2

Tags: ollydbg

I have a lot of CALL 0x000XYZW in my code. I want to tell ollydbg that 0x000XYZW address is the function "my_function", and then see CALL my_function in my CPU window. Is it possible to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Go to 0x000XYZW (press enter while selecting the call) and then use the ":" or context menu to set a label on 0x000XYZW. With x64dbg there is a direct context menu that assists you with these kind of things.

Answer (score 2):

Select the call. Line. Right click follow then hit the colon key. Ollydbg should pop up label window enter the name like. Myfunc. And that's it   press Ctrl a to analyze if need be

edit 
may be i have my shortcuts revised if it is not **colon** key try **semicolon** key 
or use the **shortcut editor** to revise labeling operation to some special key sequence of your choice
i have added a snapshot to address your comment

[image]

Comment: This procedure sets a comment on the line, it is not a label on the function that will be used in call instruction

Comment: @Bob5421 i edited the answer